# Exotel API Call.., I am getting an Error (site cant be reached) while calling Exotel API

Tags: exotel-api

I am getting the error that Site cant be reached when i make Exotel API call.

### HTML Forms

https://:@/v1/Accounts//Calls/connect

From:
  
  To:
  
  CallerId:
  
  CallType:
  
  StatusCallBack:

If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".